# envoy proxy does not give error even if pod crashes

Tags: go, kubernetes, envoyproxy

My 2 microservices are talking to each other via GRPC and I am using envoy proxy.
Microservice A is calling Microservice B and envoy container is inside Mircoservice A's pod.

My problem is that if because of any issue Microservice B pod crashed I dont get any error at A, its just keeps trying to establish connection.

My expectation is that since B pod is crashed envoy proxy should immediately give some error that cant connect or something because it knows that connection is not possible as no pods are available.

I have a standard connection timeout at A but I want envoy to fail quick in this case.

Nothing can be done at B side since it will be already crashed and A is relying on envoy proxy.

Answer (score 2):

In order to know the Status or Error when the microservice B is getting failed in  Envoy Proxy has a feature called **[Envoy Circuit Breaking.](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/circuit_breaking#circuit-breaking)** This stops sending requests to pod B as it is experiencing the issues and not able to respond. Refer to this [blog](https://blog.christianposta.com/microservices/01-microservices-patterns-with-envoy-proxy-part-i-circuit-breaking/) by Christian Posta who has explained clearly about Circuit Breaking with Envoy Proxy and its configuration with a demo.

Envoy Proxy circuit breaking is working for the microservices whereas in order to know the Pod level crash and its alert we need to use **Prometheus.** Prometheus is a good fit for microservices because you just need to expose a metrics port, and don’t need to add too much complexity or run additional services. You can find templates for Pod Crashing and Pod unhealthy [here](https://samber.github.io/awesome-prometheus-alerts/rules.html#rule-kubernetes-1-18) configure accordingly in the pods which will give you alert when Pod crashing or pod unhealthy.